# Access TextBox value of an ASP.NET page from C# class

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

Say there is a TextBox on an ASP.NET page

```
<asp:TextBox id="DateTextBox" runat="server" />
```

with some value set in the code-behind.

How to access that value from another class of C# code-file through HttpContext or any other way?

Comment: you will have to push it to that class.

Comment: Sessions are the best way to access values through another class.

Comment: Sessions seems to be VERY heavy solution for my simple task.

Comment: i would reconsider your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access a property in you page via `HttpContext` even from a static method.

in your page:

```
public string DateTextBoxText
{
    get{ return this.DateTextBox.Text; }
    set{ this.DateTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

somewhere else(even in a different dll):

```
public class Data
{
   public static string GetData() 
   { 
       TypeOfYourPage page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as TypeOfYourPage;
       if (page != null)
       {
          return page.DateTextBoxText;
          //btw, what a strange method!
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

Note that this works only if it's called from within a lifecycle of this page.

It's normally better to use `ViewState` or `Session` to maintain variables across postback. Or just use the property above directly when you have a reference to this page.

Comment: What is TypeOfYourPage for a default VS-generated .aspx? What should I put here?

Comment: @sublay: The type-of-your-page ;-) Just look at the name of the class that inherits from `Page`(e.g. in the codebehind or in the page-directive on the aspx markup).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `public property` within the control that returns a reference to the textbox.

You can then use this property to reference the textbox.

OR

You can store in into `session` and then access it in your entire application.

Comment: There is 'protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox DateTextBox;' in myfile.aspx.designer.cs Should I change to public right here?

Answer (score 1):

Store it in the `HttpContext Session` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net

```
//Storing UserName in Session
Session["DateTextBox"] = DateTextBox.Text;
```

Now, let's see how we can retrieve values from session:

```
//Check weather session variable null or not
if (Session["DateTextBox"] != null)
{
 // use it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place the value in the Session during the post back. Then access it from the Session in the other class. So in your form load event write this:

```
Session["MyValue"] = DateTextBox.Text
```

and then in the other class write this:

```
var val = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];
```