# Access a Label from one class file to another class file c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a DB Connection class file which is shown below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Asset;

namespace Asset.Modules
{
    public class Dbconn
    {

    public bool CreateDBConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssetDBConnection"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
            errorLabel.Visible = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

errorLabel is defined on my Default.aspx page as shown below;

```
<asp:Label ID="errorLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

The error that I am getting is: The name 'errorLabel' does not exist in the current context.

How do I get the Dbconn file to access the Label which is located on the default.aspx page?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Managed to resolve this in the end by following this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450158/access-textbox-value-of-an-asp-net-page-from-c-sharp-class/15450218

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can entail ...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ....accessing the database conn shared instance 

        Label myLabel = this.FindControl("errorLabel") as Label;
        myLabel.Text = "my text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the CurrentHandler back to a Page object and use FindControl in `CreateDBConnection()`.

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
Label lbl = page.FindControl("errorLabel") as Label;
lbl.Text = "There was an error.";
```